# Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'MyComboBox' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I've a custom component (MyComboBox) which has `kendo-combobox` inside.

When I use my core module, `webpack` compilation ends successfully but chrome throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'MyComboBox' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

Here is my **AppModule**:

```
import { MyComboBox } from '@my/core/control/MyComboBox';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MyComboBox
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        DragulaModule,
        MyComboBox,
        CoreModule,
        ComboBoxModule
    ],
    entryComponents: [ MyComboBox ],
    providers: [HelperService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: You should be importing Core Module instead of `MyComboBox`. Can you show how you have exported and declared `MyComboBox`?

Comment: import { ComboBoxModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';

Comment: My question was where did you export `MyComboBox`? I mean in which module? Can you please show that.

Comment: import { ComboBoxModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';

import {
    ...
    MyComboBox,
    ...
}

...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
 ...
        ComboBoxModule,
        ...
    ],
...
exports: [
 ...
        MyComboBox,
        ...
    ],

declarations: [
 ...
        MyComboBox,
        ...
    ],

Comment: It is my core module.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

**EDIT** :

This error frequently comes up when we are not `importing`, `providing`, or `declaring` the angular `modules`, `services`, `components` properly.

Make sure that we should only

1. **import** `modules` and **NOT** the `components` or `services`
2. **declare** `components` and **NOT** the `modules` or `services`.
3. **provide** `services` and **NOT** `components` or `modules`.

**Original Answer :**

You don't have to really import `MyComboBox` in your App Module. Since you have already exported it in `CoreModule`. So I would suggest you to remove `MyComboBox` from your imports array in `AppModule`. Importing `CoreModule` will give you `MyComboBox` component within `AppModule`.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      MyComboBox
     ],


    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    DragulaModule,
    CoreModule
   ],
  // viewProviders: [ DragulaService ],
  providers: [HelperService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Note : You cannot import component freely like you are doing there. It has to be contained within the module to be imported.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.
The error changed now:
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'GridModule' imported by the module 'CoreModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: This is because I use kendo's GridModule in my custom MyDataGrid

Comment: My core module again:

import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        GridModule,
        ButtonsModule,
        ComboBoxModule,
        InputsModule,
        DropDownsModule,
        UploadModule,
        LayoutModule,
        DialogModule
    ],
....

Comment: There seems to be some problem with kendo package then. Make sure you have the right version of kendo and angular-cli that is required to run.

Comment: Try installing your node modules once again.

Comment: My core module works itself. Do I need to add kendo packages in my project that uses core?

Comment: And what about Directives?

Comment: @Greg Components are nothing but the Directives with a view. So Directives should also be declared.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found it on google as I have already forgotten the process so soon.

Answer (score 26):

In my case, I was mistakenly listing the component in the `imports: []` array, which, mind you, it expects modules, not components, and that is the reason Angular complained it couldn't find the `@NgModule` definition.

Instead, I needed to list the component in the `declarations: []` list. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying creating custom module, need to do this:

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [QuantityRaritiesComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
      ],
      exports: [
        QuantityRaritiesComponent
      ],
      entryComponents: [QuantityRaritiesComponent]
    })
    
    export class SharedModulesModule { }
```

And in app.modules.ts add:

```
     imports: [
          ....
          SharedModulesModule   
     ]
```