# Ionic3 Lazy Loading Unexpected directive imported

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic3, and am in the process of implementing Lazy Loading in order to improve startup performance.

I have converted the following:

**loginemail.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginEmailPage } from './loginemail';
import { ControlMessages } from '../validation/controlMessages';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginEmailPage],
  imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginEmailPage), ControlMessages],
})
export class LoginEmailPageModule { }
```

As you can see, I import `ControlMessages`, which is a custom component (that worked perfectly with eager loading imported in `app.module.ts`).

However, when I try access the `LoginEmailPage`, I get the following runtime error:

```
core.es5.js:1085 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected directive 'ControlMessages' imported by the module 'LoginEmailPageModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
Error: Unexpected directive 'ControlMessages' imported by the module 'LoginEmailPageModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

Any advise appreciated.

p.s. `ControlMessages` is still imported in `app.module.ts` for other pages that use it.

**controlMessages.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidationService } from './validationService';

@Component({
  selector: 'control-messages',
  template: `<div *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</div>`
})
export class ControlMessages {
  @Input() control: FormControl;

  constructor() {

  }

  get errorMessage(): string {
    for (let propertyName in this.control.errors) {
      if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && this.control.touched) {
        return ValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is ControlMessages a page or common component?

Comment: Its a `Component`.

Comment: Here is a similar issue. However, the suggested solution says to put the import in `app.module.ts`, which is not conducive to lazy loading.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603515/uncaught-error-unexpected-directive-mycombobox-imported-by-the-module-appmod

Comment: no the solution says to remove the import from app.module.ts

Comment: also suggest you go through https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGokwMXPQItZmTHZQbTO4qwj_SQymFhRS_nJmiH0K3w/edit

Comment: It says to make a common module which imports and exports your common components and import that in any page you need

Comment: Thank you. I will do so.

Comment: So I can try understand the error. is the problem that the component is being imported twice? Once by `app.module.ts` on a global level, and once by `loginemail.module.ts`.

Comment: yes.. I believe that is the source of the problem

Comment: I have removed the import of the `ControlMessages` component from `app.module.ts`, and now only have it in `page1.module.ts` and `page2.module.ts`, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Need to create a `ControlMessagesModule` and rather import that.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ControlMessages } from './controlMessages';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ControlMessages],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule
  ],
  exports: [ControlMessages]
})
export class ControlMessagesModule { }
```

and

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginEmailPage } from './loginemail';
import { ControlMessagesModule } from '../validation/controlMessages.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginEmailPage],
  imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginEmailPage), ControlMessagesModule],
  exports: [LoginEmailPage]
})
export class LoginEmailPageModule { }
```