# Angular 2+, Is there any way I can declare all the components in a module and then import in app.module.ts?

Tags: angular

Hi I am trying to declare all the components in a single module and then I add that components module in imports of app.module.ts.

```
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page/landing-page.component';
import { JobSeekerComponent } from './job-seeker/job-seeker.component';
import { RecruiterComponent } from './recruiter/recruiter.component';
import { PostJobsComponent } from './recruiter/post-jobs/post-jobs.component';
import { JobSeekerLayoutComponent } from './layout/job-seeker-layout/job-seeker-layout.component';
import { RecruiterLayoutComponent } from './layout/recruiter-layout/recruiter-layout.component';
import { RecruiterHeaderComponent } from './layout/recruiter-header/recruiter-header.component';
import { AutocompleteComponent } from './common/autocomplete/autocomplete.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        LandingPageComponent,
        JobSeekerComponent,
        RecruiterComponent,
        PostJobsComponent,
        JobSeekerLayoutComponent,
        RecruiterLayoutComponent,
        RecruiterHeaderComponent,
        AutocompleteComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        LandingPageComponent,
        JobSeekerComponent,
        RecruiterComponent,
        PostJobsComponent,
        JobSeekerLayoutComponent,
        RecruiterLayoutComponent,
        RecruiterHeaderComponent,
        AutocompleteComponent
    ],
})
export class **ComponentsModule** { }
```

This is the components module which i have created and then i want to initialize this in app.module.ts. Will this work, cause when i am trying to do so, it throws an error  **Please add a @NgModule annotation.** In my app.module.ts. I did something like this.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { **ComponentsModule** } from './components';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './material';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent  
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    **ComponentsModule**
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: this link may helps you: https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-fundamentals-modules

Comment: Thanks Bro, Going throuh it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `importing` the components, you should rather `declare` them in `ComponentsModule`

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [           // declare components here
        LandingPageComponent,
        JobSeekerComponent,
        RecruiterComponent,
        PostJobsComponent,
        JobSeekerLayoutComponent,
        RecruiterLayoutComponent,
        RecruiterHeaderComponent,
        AutocompleteComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        LandingPageComponent,
        JobSeekerComponent,
        RecruiterComponent,
        PostJobsComponent,
        JobSeekerLayoutComponent,
        RecruiterLayoutComponent,
        RecruiterHeaderComponent,
        AutocompleteComponent
    ],
})
```

Comment: Unexpected module 'CommonModule' declared by the module 'ComponentsModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation. This is what i am getting with this.

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603515/uncaught-error-unexpected-directive-mycombobox-imported-by-the-module-appmod/43605696#43605696 to understand better so as to what should be imported, provided and declared.

Comment: You have probably declared `CommonModule` in `ComponentsModule`. Instead you should `import` it in `ComponentsModule`.

Comment: Thanks Amit! It worked. I had imported CommonModule, that's why it wasn't working. Also, There's an Issue with RoutingModule. Do I need to import this twice once in app.module.ts and the same in ComponentsModule??

Comment: If you meant `RouterModule`, yes you will be importing it in all the `routing` files to register your routes like `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` in app module and `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` in child modules.

Comment: Ok!! Got it!! Thanks bro :)