# Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'MatFormFieldModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angular

I am getting next error on installing Angular Material to the Angular 7 Project:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'MatFormFieldModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

I am putting **app.module.ts** code below:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatFormFieldModule , MatInputModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule ,
    MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'MyComboBox' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603515/uncaught-error-unexpected-directive-mycombobox-imported-by-the-module-appmod)

Comment: Add `MatFormFieldModule` to imports array. Only `Components/Directives/Pipes` should be added to declarations array. Here `MatFormFieldModule` is a module

Answer (score 1):

Please add 'MatFormFieldModule' within import array. Like as below:
    
    `@NgModule({
     declarations: [
      AppComponent
     ],
     imports: [    ,
      MatFormFieldModule,
      BrowserModule,
      OtherAppModule
     ],
     providers: [],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})`