# Failed: Unexpected directive 'ContactDetailsComponent' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have created a new component and did ng test, but failing with the below error

> Failed: Unexpected directive 'ContactDetailsComponent' imported by the
>   module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AdditionalContactDetailsComponent } from './additional-contact-details.component';
import { EdlInputModule, EdlIconModule, EdlMessagesModule } from '@fedex/ddt';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ContactDetailsComponent } from '../contact-details/contact-details.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

fdescribe('AdditionalContactDetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: AdditionalContactDetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AdditionalContactDetailsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [EdlInputModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        EdlIconModule,
        EdlMessagesModule,
        ContactDetailsComponent,
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [AdditionalContactDetailsComponent],
      providers: [FormBuilder]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AdditionalContactDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Remove `ContactDetailsComponent` from imports array and add it to `declarations` aray.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'MyComboBox' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603515/uncaught-error-unexpected-directive-mycombobox-imported-by-the-module-appmod)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Remove `ContactDetailsComponent` component from the import array and add it in the declaration array. **Components** are always placed in a declaration array and **modules** are placed in import array.

**Here is the solution:**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AdditionalContactDetailsComponent } from './additional-contact-details.component';
import { EdlInputModule, EdlIconModule, EdlMessagesModule } from '@fedex/ddt';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ContactDetailsComponent } from '../contact-details/contact-details.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

fdescribe('AdditionalContactDetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: AdditionalContactDetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AdditionalContactDetailsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [EdlInputModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        EdlIconModule,
        EdlMessagesModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [AdditionalContactDetailsComponent, ContactDetailsComponent],
      providers: [FormBuilder]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AdditionalContactDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: My Lord, I could not spot that error issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You just cleared so many doubts with this one line _"Components are always placed in a declaration array and modules are placed in import array."_

Comment: This has been an interesting adjustment for our team with the switch to standalone components in Angular 17. Thanks for sharing this answer as it helped us fix our tests for our none-standalone components.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, just in my case I accidentally placed MockComponent inside imports, instead of declarations. **As both tested and mocked component were from the same (current) module.**

Incorrect:

```
imports: [
        MockComponent(MyComponent),
      ],
```

Correct:

```
 declarations: [
    MockComponent(MyComponent),
  ],
```