# How do I avoid a "Unexpected module 'HttpClientModule' ... annotation" error?

Tags: angular, http, dependency-injection, module

I'm using Angular 7 and trying to read JSON data from a Rails 5 app.  I have the below in my src/app/app.component.ts file ...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  books;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    http.get('http://localhost:3000/books.json')
      .subscribe(res => this.books = res);
  }
}
```

and this in my ./src/app/app.module.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HttpClientModule,
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

However, when I visit my web page at http://localhost:4200 I get this error

```
compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'HttpClientModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)
    at eval (compiler.js:15296)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15278)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34413)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34374)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34268)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:239)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5578)
    at eval (main.ts:11)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'MyComboBox' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603515/uncaught-error-unexpected-directive-mycombobox-imported-by-the-module-appmod)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `HttpClientModule` under **`imports`** not under **`declarations`**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [    
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```