# How to import a component into two pages?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have a structure like this:

- home - page
- home2 - page
- test-component - component

I need to be able to use the component(`<app-test-component></app-test-component>`) on both pages.

If I just use the tag:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   'app-test-component' is not a known element:

If I just import (`import {TestComponentComponent} from '../test-component/test-component.component'`) into home.module.ts and put it in the module import:

> core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected
>   directive 'TestComponentComponent' imported by the module
>   'HomePageModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

A similar error if added to declarations.

[Git.](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/ionic-import-error)

How to import a component on both pages and use?

Comment: isherwood, Do you mean in app.component.ts? I imported, nothing has changed.

Comment: Imported (import {TestComponentComponent} from './test-component/test-component.component'),  declarat(declarations: [AppComponent, TestComponentComponent],), same error (core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected directive 'TestComponentComponent' imported by the module 'HomePageModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.). I updated the github example.

Comment: This is not so, I did not find mention of this in the official documentation. But I saw a couple of questions where it turned out to import the component onto several pages, about in these issues a different version of the package is visible. Can you make a simple example on ionic where would I get what I want or your version of this task?

Comment: Reopening since it's not clear what the problem is. Here's the potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603515/uncaught-error-unexpected-directive-mycombobox-imported-by-the-module-appmod

Comment: Asked 2 years, 5 months ago  - this is a different version

Comment: I don't believe protocol for imports and declarations has changed.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @VINET : You should not import `TestComponentComponent,` in `import`. Its for the modules. Also, you need to export the `component` other than `declaration`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few changes that you should make:

1. You should not import `component` as I can see in the code.
2. Rearrange the project structure, and move **reusable** component such as `TestComponent` into a shared component. To give you an example, I'll give below example where I have created shared module names as `TestModule`

```
/app
  /home
   -home.component.ts
   -home.module.ts

  /test
   -test.component.ts
   -test.module.ts

-app.component.ts
-app.module.ts
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HomeModule, RouterModule.forRoot([{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }])],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**test.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [TestComponent],
  exports: [TestComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class TestModule {}
```

**home.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TestModule
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

This set of project structure would certainly help you to reuse `test.module` features. Let me know if you need more code.

Comment: Thank you, your option works! I tried a similar option, but it declared and there was an error. Everyone who needs an example will be on git.

Answer (score 0):

Declare TestComponentComponent only in home.module.

**home.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage, TestComponentComponent]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: If you import into two pages, then one of them will really work. When going to the second page there will be an error. (ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type TestComponentComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: HomePageModule and Home2PageModule! Please consider moving TestComponentComponent to a higher module that imports HomePageModule and Home2PageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes TestComponentComponent then import that NgModule in HomePageModule and Home2PageModule.)