# Class is not an Angular module for external library

Tags: angular, angular10

I have created a simple `Angular` app and added a custom library (same project):

`ng new my-library`
`ng generate library my-library-lib`

Then to test this simple library in a **different** project, I built the lib:
`ng build my-library-lib`

I linked the lib in dist folder and linked it to a different project and imported the `MyLibraryLibModule` in my `SharedModule`

`{ MyLibraryLibModule } from 'my-library-lib`

`imports: [..., MyLibraryLibModule]` --> throws error: `class is not an Angular Module`

This is a simple project I did to redo everything from scratch, did not change anything in `tsconfig` files etc. Looked online but couldn't find any solution.

To test it:
**Library repo:**
https://github.com/GCour/ui-library

**Simple project repo:**
https://github.com/GCour/ui-test

`tsconfig.lib.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

`tsconfing.lib.prod.json`

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.lib.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationMap": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "my-library-lib": [
        "dist/my-library-lib/my-library-lib",
        "dist/my-library-lib"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which Angular version are you using?

Comment: @yurzui Angular 10 (10.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

If you are **asking about use in developer a local library** you should create your library in production

```
ng build my-lib --prod
```

then use `npm link` to create locally your library

```
cd dist
cd my-lib
npm link
```

If all is ok, you can import in another project of your computer, you can check if the lib is added to your local npm in

```
C:\Users\[your-user]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\my-lib
```

Now the only thing you need to use in another project of your computer using `npm link my-library`

```
cd c:\my-another-app\src
npm link my-library
```

And use as usually, in your app.module

```
   import {myLibModule} from 'my-lib'
   //or import {MyLibService} from 'my-lib/public-api' 

   ...
   imports: [myLibModule}
```

Comment: I did all that but it keeps saying 'Class is not an Angular module'. I've tried to link it in couple of projects but all got the same error.

Comment: has you build your library using `--prod`?

Comment: Yes I did. However, if I use `npm link` it throws that error but not when I copy the dist folder to the `node_modules`. But then he can't find any services I provided in that module..

Comment: I have added the 2 projects in the OP

Comment: I think that you can use: `import {MyLibService} from 'my-lib/public-api'` to import the service (I just corrected the answer) -really I'm a few newbie with librarys :(-

Comment: Indeed that does work, but I still cannot import the module in the shared folder. It would mean I need to import all the services one by one, right?

Comment: @Eliseo, I believe we don't need `--prod` flag while working with libraries. It is a common myth among developers but the official docs clearly mention that library builder, ensures that the library is always built with the AOT compiler, without the need to specify the --prod flag.

https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#getting-started

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pyronlaboratory/ng-pyronlaboratory) for reference which demonstrates the setup and integration of the custom libraries using `npm link`.

### Angular CLI build command uses a different builder and invokes a different build tool for libraries than it does for applications.

---

- Angular CLI has a different mechanism for building libraries, based on `ng-packagr` unlike for building applications, which uses `@angular-devkit/build-angular` and is based on `webpack`.
- The build system for libraries is only added to your dependencies when you add a library using `ng generate library my-lib`. If you've been manually setting up the infrastructure, you might wanna make sure of this by verifying your config files.

### Be careful with TypeScript path mappings..

---

- Since there is a difference in the build mechanism, the TypeScript source gets converted to a totally different JavaScript code in the built library than it would in a built application.
- For this reason, an app that depends on a library should only use TypeScript path mappings that point to the built library. TypeScript path mappings should not point to the library source .ts files.

As stated in the official docs -

> .. When you build your own library, it has to find the mapping in
> your tsconfig paths.

**NOTE:** Generating a library with the Angular CLI automatically adds its path to the `tsconfig` file. The Angular CLI uses the `tsconfig` paths to tell the build system where to find the library.

### Is your application using code from an old library build!

---

- Every time a file within the source code is changed, a partial build is performed that emits the new changes from the source code.
- If you believe your changes in the library code are not reflected in your app, your app is probably using an old build of the library.
- You can rebuild your library whenever you make changes to it, but this extra step takes time. We can make use of Angular built-in Incremental build feature. Incremental builds can be run as a background process in your dev environment.
- Add the `--watch` flag to the build command: `$ ng build my-lib --watch`

### Need to share your library code outside the application's scope?

---

- Publish your library on npm for global users.
- Create a local link for sharing within a private network.

---

*since the op has been edited and is looking for creating a local link, the following explains only the second bit. To publish your library on `npm-registry`, you can refer to [the official angular docs on publishing libraries on npm registry](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#publishing-your-library). If you're new to the npm registry, and this is the first time you're publishing a library, you might wanna check out [the various grounds to cover when publishing your libraries on npm registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/contributing-packages-to-the-registry/)*

---

While working with `npm link` ...

- Once you build your library, in order to verify if it's done correctly, go to the dist/ folder of your library workspace and verify the `package.json` file. The `package.json`, should have an attribute `main`. Make sure it is linked with a file extension of *.js* and not a *.ts*
- Now you can use `npm link` within your library workspace. It creates a reference pointer - *a symlink* - within the local node environment directing towards your library.
- Once the local reference is created, go to your project workspace, and use `npm link <library-name>`. Make sure, it's the **library name** and not the **library-workspace name**.
- In the project workspace, within the `node_modules` you should be able to see your library with an '**@**' appended to it. Now you can easily import relevant components and services from your library into your projects `app.module.ts`.. or lazy-load them if you prefer that approach.

Likewise..

```
import { FooModule } from 'foo-library';
...
```

Comment: I have edited my post with some config files. Let me know if you need more

Comment: bear in mind that I'm not using this library in the same project where I could just use the path. It will be published in a package and then used in a different project. So for now I'm using `npm link`

Comment: I have added the 2 projects in post

Comment: Hey @Greg, thanks for posting the GitHub repositories. Unfortunately, the .gitignore file in your project has restricted posting the build or dist folder. It's still tricky to debug without the dist folder..

Comment: I've updated my answer and posted a working demo on GitHub. Let me know if that works out for you..

Comment: I cannot install the projects somehow. However, I see that you're importing the component but shouldn't be that in declarations? Also, if I had a Pipe how would I import that without using a module, or if I had more than 1 component, pipe, services.. Best would be just importing a module but that is not working

Comment: @Greg, indeed you should use the module file to make the imports, I wrote that for explanation purpose. I've made edits. I've added a readme file in the repository, which should help you to set up the project and library. I've also included some test cases and screenshots of the implementation for you to refer.. The repository also includes a custom pipe in the library for your reference.

Comment: I didn't see any changes in your repository, but I am quite positive now, that your error is not related to publishing and using custom libraries but rather a simple import/export error within your modules. I would suggest you, read these docs https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules alongside this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603515/uncaught-error-unexpected-directive-mycombobox-imported-by-the-module-appmod#