# Angular - How to use local library inside of another local library

Tags: angular, ivy, angular10

I'm creating some libraries in order to use on my projects. To do so I created two fundamental library named core and shared

```
src
projects
 - core
 - shared
```

I'm able to build my core library into `dist/core` which in a path that defined as `@base/core` in root `tsconfig.json` (which is inherited by `tsconfig.lib.prod.json`)

In my project files I'm able to use CoreModule imported from `@base/core`. But I cant access my CoreModule inside of `projects/shared`. When I build the shared it throws errors about it cant find my models, services, pipes inside of the CoreModule.

How can I make it my shared library to resolve CoreModule in dist folder. My current angular version is `10.2.0`

Comment: this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930778/class-is-not-an-angular-module-for-external-library/64968095#64968095 help you?

Comment: @Eliseo still same

Comment: @Eliseo the weird part is that, npm link worked, it created symlink to core folder. but still not able to resolve, even if it globally defined

Comment: @Eliseo oh wait it worked I just made something wrong. I can't tell how I appreciate you