# Using Angular Library component in local project - not working

Tags: angular

I have created a angular workspace that contains my project and library.
Below is the project structure:

[image: FOLDER STRUCTURE]

I have build my library -(This uses form module)

```
ng build demo-lib
```

and it compiles successfully and creates a folder inside dist folder.

Now I have imported the module inside app.module.ts and added under import:

```
import { DemoFormComponent, DemoLibModule } from 'demo-lib'
.
.
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DemoLibModule,
    DemoFormComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But when I serve my application I get below error, I am not sure what I am doing wrong :-

```
Error: dist/demo-lib/lib/demo-form/demo-form.component.d.ts:4:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the dependency (demo-lib) which declares DemoFormComponent has not been processed correctly by ngcc.

4 export declare class DemoFormComponent implements OnInit {
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Which version of Angular?

Comment: It might be related to the move from [View Engine to Ivy](https://blog.angular.io/upcoming-improvements-to-angular-library-distribution-76c02f782aa4).

Comment: I don't know if this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930778/class-is-not-an-angular-module-for-external-library/64968095#64968095) is related

Comment: --Angular CLI: 13.1.2

Comment: @rveerd I am creating a new library in angular 13 , not sure why it should be using view engine ... do we need to set ivy or it is default , I am not sure i read somewhere from angular 12 onwards ivy is default ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only import modules into you module. You cannot (and don't need to) import components.

Your library module exports the component. That is enough for Angular to find the component when you use it in your application.

```js
import { DemoLibModule } from 'demo-lib'
.
.
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DemoLibModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot removing that worked ... such a silly mistake and I wasted a whole day for this .