# forRoot method Angular library not firing

Tags: angular, azure-devops, angular-library

i have created an angular library with a static forRoot method to pass static data from the application to the library so i created an forRoot method to handle this

```
export class DynamicFormBuilderModule {
  public static forRoot(config: Configurations): ModuleWithProviders<DynamicFormBuilderModule> {
    console.log('inside forRoot method',config)
    return {
      ngModule: DynamicFormBuilderModule,
      providers: [
        ConfigService,
        {
          provide: Configurations,
          useValue: config,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

this is passed data from the application to the library

```
 DynamicFormBuilderModule.forRoot({
  production: environment.production,
  baseUrl: environment.baseUrl,
  maxMaskCharacterLength: environment.maxMaskCharacterLength,
  rejectedExtentions: environment.rejectedExtentions,
  attachmentImage: environment.attachmentImage,
  attachmentFile: environment.attachmentFile,
  attachmentBoth: environment.attachmentBoth,
  socketAutomaticReconnectIntervals: environment.socketAutomaticReconnectIntervals,
  undoCount: environment.undoCount,
}),
```

the problem is after building the lib and uploading it into devops artifact and downloaded into the node_module folder

i got all the sent data from application is blank so after adding some console logs inside the forRoot created inside the library module i found that the forRoot is not firing i have no idea why and i have spent a lot of time trying to debug but with no luck.

here is a snap shot of the uploaded artifact files
[image]

UPDATE : here is my ConfigService constructor

```
constructor(@Optional() config?: Configurations) {
    if (config) {
      this._production = config.production;
      this._baseUrl = config.baseUrl;
      this._maxMaskCharacterLength = config.maxMaskCharacterLength;
      this._rejectedExtentions = config.rejectedExtentions;
      this._attachmentImage = config.attachmentImage;
      this._attachmentFile = config.attachmentFile;
      this._attachmentBoth = config.attachmentBoth;
      this._socketAutomaticReconnectIntervals = config.socketAutomaticReconnectIntervals;
      this._undoCount = config.undoCount;
    }
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately i didn't get what u mean can you explain please ? thanks in advace.

Comment: Can you show the constructor of your `ConfigService`?

Comment: yeah sure question updated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Well. The method cannot not fire as it's being called from the code. You should check the build logs for errors and the console in the browser for errors as well. The only way for method not to fire is for an error to happen before the method's call. Also worth checking if the lib version used by the app is correct. Stackblitz example/repo where the issue is reproduced would be much more insightful to provide you with the help

Comment: @Sergey unfortunately i have tried everything i can and found that there is no error in the console and i cannot use stackblitz because stackblitz has no library feature and cant reproduce my issue there.

Comment: is there any update on this issue please ? it took me more than 2 days to solve and still no luck.

Comment: its working fine when iam serving the app via ng serve but the issue appears when i try to build it using ng build library-name

Answer (score 0):

I made a little example that work. I put all the differents components and service (it is a very large post, sorry)

**Library**

app-lib.module

```
import { ModuleWithProviders,NgModule,Optional,SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';

import { AppLibComponent } from './app-lib.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 
import { AppLibService,UserServiceConfig } from './app-lib.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppLibComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [AppLibComponent]
})
export class AppLibModule { 
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule?: AppLibModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error(
        'GreetingModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
    }
  }

  public static forRoot(config: UserServiceConfig): ModuleWithProviders<AppLibModule> {
    console.log(config)
    return {
      ngModule: AppLibModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: AppLibService, useValue: config }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

app-lib.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppLibService } from './app-lib.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-app-lib',
  template: `
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p *ngIf="user">
    <i>Welcome, {{user}}</i>
  <p>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class AppLibComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'NgModules';
  user = '';

  constructor(userService: AppLibService) {
    this.user = userService.userName;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

app-lib.service

```
import { Injectable,Optional } from '@angular/core';

let nextId = 1;

export class UserServiceConfig {
  userName = 'Philip Marlowe';
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppLibService {
  private id = nextId++;

  constructor(@Optional() config?: UserServiceConfig) {
    if (config) { this._userName = config.userName; }
  }

  get userName() {
    // Demo: add a suffix if this service has been created more than once
    const suffix = this.id > 1 ? ` times ${this.id}` : '';
    return this._userName + suffix;
  }
  private _userName = 'Sherlock Holmes';
}
```

**aplication**

app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppLibModule} from 'app-lib'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,CommonModule,AppLibModule.forRoot({userName: environment.userName})
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:`
  <lib-app-lib></lib-app-lib>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app-library-use';
}
```

the enviroment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  userName:"User Developer"
};
```

the enviroment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  userName:"User Production"
};
```

NOTE I use this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930778/class-is-not-an-angular-module-for-external-library/64968095#64968095) to generate the library in local

NOTE: I had problems because at fisrt, I not imported the commonModule to the library

NOTE: I put in github the [two projects](https://github.com/EliseoPlunker/example-lib-forRoot)

Comment: well thanks a lot for this great post BUT i already found the issue which is located inside my DynamicFormBuilderModule  inside the provide property instead of the configuration class i had to pass an string and replaced it inside the config service with @Inject 

@Optional() @Inject('environment') config?: Configurations instead of @Optional() config?: Configurations

Comment: I'm happy you solved :)

Comment: thanks a lot i ran into another one :D iam feeling unlucky or stupid i dont know :D

Comment: in my lib module i have a message component which should be in the entry components array and inside this message component i have a custom component called button component after build iam getting 

1. If 'dfb-button' is an Angular component and it has 'buttonSize' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'dfb-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

Comment: have u seen anything like this before ?

Answer (score 0):

if your lib is correctly built, you should see in local all the components it's supposed to expose. Remember that everything that you want to expose outside your lib must be **declared** in the `publi-api.ts` file.

My advice : first test your integration of your lib components in local with a "sandbox" app situated next to your lib in a directory like /projects. This must always work if your tsconfig.json does declare your lib correctly :

```json
"paths": {
      "@me/lib-dfb": [
        "dist/lib-dfb/lib-dfb",
        "dist/lib-dfb"
      ],
}
```

Only when this works, test in pack / publish mode.

Comment: well yeah thanks i have made this step already BUT i already found the issue which is located inside my DynamicFormBuilderModule inside the provide property instead of the configuration class i had to pass an string and replaced it inside the config service with @Inject @Optional() @Inject('environment') config?: Configurations instead of @Optional() config?: Configurations –

Comment: Well it depends on how your Configurations are declared as provider. This `@Inject` might be needed if it's not `@Injectable` of out of the "scope". But without your code I can't really tell :) Anyway, I'm glad this works for your initial issue !

Comment: my service has @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

Comment: so i think this is not the case , but iam super glade because we are debugging something werid happend i feel like the angular community is still here , thank you guys so much.

Comment: You're welcome, it's indeed great to be able to work on some hard issues with others from the community ! Cheers !